# Building lms-suit, OpenGL error

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile lms-suit, which is a control software for Lime Microsystems LMS family of transceivers. Downloaded from gitbub here: 
https://github.com/myriadrf/lms-suite

Been following their "Compilation guide windows" that is located:
LMS6002D/lms-suit/docs.

Done the following:

1. installed CMake
2. installed Visual Studio (community)
3. installed wxWidgets
4. Build wxwidget library using VS, no errors.
5. installed EZ-USB FX3 SDK
6. extracted FFTW
7. copied lms-suit folder from lms-suite-master\LMS6002D to c:\
8. ran cmake, no errors reported after giving it correct FFTW path. [cmake conf screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ91B.png)
9. opened up lms-suit.sln from the build directory and then tried to build it with VS.

   However here is where I get two errors, and I am not sure what I am missing, or which step that could have caused the errors.
   Both errors are in OpenGLGraph.cpp:

   identifier "m_glContext" is undefined
   lms-suite   c:\lms-suit\lms-suite\src\gui_src\fft\oglGraph\OpenGLGraph.cpp  55

   Error (active)      too few arguments in function call  lms-suite
   c:\lms-suit\lms-suite\src\gui_src\fft\oglGraph\OpenGLGraph.cpp  583

I am assuming that the github code is correct, and that I have done something wrong in the earlier steps. Almost looks to me like I am missing a header file?

Comment: `m_glContext` doesn't exist but the [header](https://github.com/myriadrf/lms-suite/blob/master/LMS6002D/lms-suite/src/gui_src/fft/oglGraph/OpenGLGraph.h#L333) contains `m_DrawingContext`. [SetCurrent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_g_l_canvas.html#a9f9ab3909606484e717904064d4e7b4f) expects a context, but [there](https://github.com/myriadrf/lms-suite/blob/master/LMS6002D/lms-suite/src/gui_src/fft/oglGraph/OpenGLGraph.cpp#L583)'s nothing. Short: lms-suite is buggy or deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little sleuthing, I found this in the wxWindows repo:

See: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blame/master/include/wx/glcanvas.h#L297

```
#if WXWIN_COMPATIBILITY_2_8
    wxGLContext *m_glContext;
#endif // WXWIN_COMPATIBILITY_2_8
```

So it looks like lms-suite was written for an older version of wxWidgets (circa 2007?).  You will either have to recompile wxWidgets with the right configuration, get an older version of wxWidgets, or update the lms-suite code.

Comment: wxWidgets 3.0 is still built with with 2.8 compatibility turned on, so using it should work. If the OP used 3.1.0, then 2.8 compatibility is still there but turned off by default, and it would be necessary to rebuild wxWidgets (change the corresponding symbol in `wx/msw/setup.h`, then rebuild everything) with it turned on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried first to edit setup.h and rebuild and it worked. However, the GUI did size correctly. So I reinstalled VS 2013 and wxwidget 3.0.2, and its working :)